# Acceder a dato de estructura

Tags: c, lista, estructuras-de-datos

El programa tendría que trabajar con listas en C. Tiene que poder leer enteros que ingresa el usuario y hacer operaciones con dichos números, como por ejemplo insertar elementos al frente, mostrar un elemento y también la posibilidad de borrar un elemento ingresado.
Pero tira los siguiente errores en tiempo de diseño

```
#ifndef _Lista
#define _Lista

typedef struct
{
    int info, sig;
} nodoL;

typedef nodoL* lista;

void insFront(lista *L, int n);
int mostrar(lista L);
void borrar(lista *L, int n);
#endif
```

Archivo myLista.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "myLista.h"

void insFront (lista *L, int n){
    lista aux = malloc(sizeof(nodoL));
    aux -> info = n;
    aux -> sig = L; 
    L=aux;
    printf("Se agrego el %d a la lista\n",n);
}

int mostrar(lista L){
    int i=0;
    if (L!=NULL){
        i=1;
        printf(" |%d|->",L->info);
        mostrar(L->sig); //<-warning: passing argument 1 of 'mostrar' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]|
    }
    return i;
    }

void borrar(lista *L, int n){
    lista aux = *L; 
    *L = *L -> sig; //<-error: request for member 'sig' in something not a structure or union
    free (aux);   
}
```

Tira los siguientes errores:

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'mostrar' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]|
>
> error: request for member 'sig' in something not a structure or union|

¿Cómo se puede solventar esos errores?

Comment: que quieres hacer?? que hace tu algoritmo?? aclara tu pregunta

Comment: Hola Alejandro, aunque los errores parecen claros, te recomiendo que leas [ask] en el centro de ayuda para encontrar consejos sobre cómo mejorar las preguntas. Por ejemplo, sería bueno que añadieses una descripción de lo que quieres realizar con tu programa, la línea donde ocurre el error (parece que lo haces en los comentarios pero en inglés), si ocurre en tiempo de ejecución o compilación, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Los errores están claros como el agua, tal vez no estás familiarizado a los mismos por estar en Inglés, permíteme traducirlos:

> alarma: pasar el argumento 1 de 'mostrar' crea un puntero a partir de un entero sin una conversión [activado por defecto]

¿Por qué sucede esto?, la función `mostrar` tiene la siguiente firma:

```
int mostrar(lista L);
```

El primer parámetro es de tipo `lista` el cuál es un alias de un puntero a `nodoL`:

```
typedef nodoL* lista;
```

Lo que quiere decir que la firma de `mostrar` sería:

```
int mostrar(nodoL* L);
```

La llamada que estás haciendo y que provoca el error es la siguiente:

```
mostrar(L->sig);
```

El dato `sig` tiene tipo entero (`int`):

```
typedef struct
{
    int info, sig;
           // ^^^ <----- sig es entero
} nodoL;
```

Así que en la llamada `mostrar(L->sig)` estás pasando un entero (`int`) a una función que espera un puntero a `nodoL` (`nodoL*`) y esto provoca la alarma.

> error: petición del miembro 'sig' en algo que no es una estructura o unión

El miembro `sig` de `nodoL` es n tipo de dato entero (`int`):

```
typedef struct
{
    int info, sig;
           // ^^^ <----- sig es entero
} nodoL;
```

Pero lo estás tratando como un puntero:

```
//   v <----- Puntero
*L = *L -> sig
//         ^^^ <----- Entero
```

---

Seguramente querías que `sig` fuese un puntero a `nodoL`:

```
typedef struct nodo
{
    int info;
    struct nodo *sig;
} nodoL;
```

No hagas un alias de `nodo` llamado `lista`, los nodos no son listas.

Comment: `typedef struct nodo
{
    int info;
    nodo* sig; //<< tira este error error: unknown type name 'nodo'
} nodoL;`

Comment: [A mi no me sucede](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CtTXvAPceHn5UGoR), algo tienes "*raro*" en tu código.

Comment: hay que agregar `struct` antes del `nodo* sig;`
La línea quedaría así `struct nodo* sig;`

Comment: Cierto @AlejandroCaro olvidé poner el compilador en modo [tag:c], corrijo.

Comment: Con el ejemplo que pusiste también anduvo.
Lo saqué de otra pregunta de Stack over

Comment: Igual tira una advertencia porque el contenido de `nodo.info` nunca se especifica

Comment: lo que tendrías que hacer. No se si la advertencia la tira adrede, lo bien lees la variable `nodo.info` como entera o bien asignarle un valor, por ejemplo 0 `nodo.info=0;`